# Django: Get the form name or id from template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

If you have multiple forms

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)

class SecondNameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

is there a way that, in your template, you can figure out if `form` in inside `context` belongs to `NameForm` or `SecondNameForm`

I have a custom widget that in its html, it uses the `id=""` identifier (which should be unique in the whole html).

I want to assign the id to something like

`id="{{form.name}}_{{field.val}}"` or
`id="{{form.id}}_{{field.val}}"` or

where `{{form.name}}` and `{{form.id}}` is some value associated with the form instance and not the form's content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a unique [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) for each form, then the fields will all have unique ids.

```
form1 = NameForm(prefix='name') 
form2 = SecondNameForm(prefix='second_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you can do `form.__class__.__name__` but this doesn't work inside a template because django templates do not recognize variables that begin with `__`

The best thing to do in your case would be to simply create an extra context variable that identifies the form name

```
id="{{form_name}}_{{field.val}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with forms you can get the id from the templates

> {{ form.instance.pk ]}