# how to get form name from post request using django?

Tags: python, django, post, request

How to get form name(attribute) from post request using django?

I cant image how to resolve this.

Please let me know.

Comment: do you want to add logic by form name inside the view?

Comment: the form I said is in template. sorry.

Comment: i understand it, but why you need form name in the post data?

Comment: if you really need it, add `name` attribute to your submit button. It will send as post data.

Comment: Mr. Bear
The page sends two type post to server, so I want to switch the logic.

Comment: itzMEonTV
thank you! but I dont know how to get the name. let me know how to get.

Comment: this is pretty janky, but it works. `list(request.POST.keys())[-1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Get the form name or id from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494064/django-get-the-form-name-or-id-from-template)